# Github: Several commits behind, no shown differences

Tags: git, git-fork

In my github fork (master branch) of the public repository `geopandas` I can see the following notification:

> This branch is 28 commits behind geopandas:master.

I think this means that I somehow need to merge those commits from the remote master to my remote fork. However when I open the "Compare" tab (to check what these 28 commits are), it shows the following:

[image]

I would have expected to see a list of the 28 commits and what they are. So I conclude that there is something fundamentally flawed in my understanding of how the forking workflow works.

Why does the "28 commits behind" message not imply actual changes in the compare tab?

Comment: Take a look at the direction of the arrow in the screenshot.

Comment: how do I reverse the arrow direction?

Comment: You can swap the base and head repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a symmetric comparison in the case of a pull request. One branch is the source, the other is the destination.

As alfunx points out in comment, you have here your branch as the source, which is the contrary of what you wanted.

Swap the repos in the select boxes to make `geopandas/geopandas` the source.